# Filter properties of standard classes in Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, class, properties

Is there any way that I can filter some properties of an “extends” class?  For example I have this:

```
package src {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public dynamic class code01 extends MovieClip {
     //// code
```

and then I just want “`alpha`” property and “`scaleX`” and “`scaleY`” and nothing else from `MovieClip` class. The reason is, if I have numbers of instance from this class, then my performance will not be interesting. So if I can filter unnecessary properties, then my performance will be better though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties cannot be "filtered", and you looking for optimization in wrong place. If you don't use frames, extend Sprite class. If you don't need containers, use Shape class. Why MovieClip? It was the only display object in AS2, but now you have choice.

Comment: +1 Thats exactly right, also by making the class dynamic, I think your achieving the exact opposite of optimization.

Comment: Dynamic classes are indeed somewhat bigger (this can be measured with getSize() global function) and dynamic property lookup is hardly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inheritance if you just want a few properties. (In Actionscript, this can be more difficult to enforce than in other languages.) If you can, it might be better to do what you want to do using composition - define a private variable inside your Code01 class that contains an object of type Movieclip.